# Инициализация std::span с помощью фигурных скобок

Tags: c++, инициализация

```cpp
#include <span>

std::span<const int> c1 = {{1, 2, 3}}; // OK
std::span<const int> c2 = {1, 2, 3};   // CE
std::span<int> m1 = {{1, 2, 3}};       // CE
std::span<int> m2 = {1, 2, 3};         // CE
```

Почему первая строка компилируется, а последующие - нет?

> error: could not convert from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to
> 'std::span'

Comment: Потому что нет подходящих конструкторов.

Comment: Конструктора нет. Не знаю, честно говоря, какой в первом случае сработал... Верояно с `std::array`

Comment: Если конструктор эксплиситный, то `T t = {arg};` не сработает

Comment: Две последние - очевидно: получается доступ для изменения к литералу.